# Can I prevent XCode 4 from stepping into synthesized properties?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, xcode4

If I want to step into a method which is being passed synthesized properties, I first have to step into and out of each of those properties.  Is there a way to tell XCode to ignore them?

Comment: I do not think this is possible since the synthesized property is just acting as a default getter. I do believe however you can just press step into twice. Although not a solution it is a bit quicker.

Comment: I assume you mean that even though you've synthesized the property, you must still have a customer getter.  Correct?

Comment: Nope - no custom getter.  In fact nowadays I don't even have an @synthesize line; it's all autosynthesized.  But XCode still steps in and out.

Comment: That's odd.  XCode doesn't do that to me.  What hot-keys are you pressing to continue?

Comment: Where is it stepping in and out if it's autosynthesized?  To the header file definition?

Comment: @RLH: That's right.  I haven't tried it in 4.6 yet.

Comment: @RLH: I have now.. unfortunately the behaviour is still there in 4.6.

Comment: Ok, I've found an answer.  Writing it up now.  Be looking for it in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Hey Simon, I'm curious what you thought of my answer.  I'm not necessarily looking for a few rep points.  I am curious as to if this solution is at all viable for your circumstance.

Comment: As you say, directly using ivars like that is discouraged, and I don't want to change my code; I want to change XCode's behaviour.  It is an interesting thought, though.

Comment: Well, after looking extensively into this, I couldn't find any other method of stopping this "annoyance".  The only other, semi-reasonable solution I've found is to put a breakpoint on the first line of each method that I am testing.  That way, when I get to the code that calls the method, that is receiving the property, all I have to do is continue and the code will break at the next line.  This can be a nuisance, too, under certain circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think is possible: property are a MERE glue code, so the compiler sees and compile the actual glue-code/macro expansion, so in binary code there are these calls and debugger will step in these pieces of binary.

To be more precise every self.XY is "CALL" to another function in asm..

in simulator we could see:

```
0x7853:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x7856:  movl   -24(%ebp), %ecx
0x7859:  movl   -48(%ebp), %edx
0x785c:  movl   92138(%edx), %esi
0x7862:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x7865:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x7869:  movl   %ecx, 8(%esp)
0x786d:  calll  0x15ed2                   ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
```

this is a self.XY code.

Comment: XCode has the debug symbols too, though - is there anything in them that might help?